# jquery wysiwyg throws "Object doesn't support this property or method" on postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, wysiwyg

I have a textbox which i applied on it jq wysiwyg:

```
public static void PopulateWysiwyg(this SafeTextBox tb)
{
    string script =
@"
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('#safe_text_box').wysiwyg();
});
";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        tb,
        tb.GetType(), 
        tb.ClientID + "_wysiwyg", 
        script.Replace("safe_text_box", tb.ClientID), true
    );
}
```

When I click a postback button on the form, the wysiwyg js throws an exception:
[image: java script exception]

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you see the bit of code that is commented out in the wysiwyg plugin.  Re-enable that bit of code and take out the return statement above it.  That code implements the browser-aware bit that will make the code work in IE.

Comment: I wrapped the first in a try, and put the second in the catch block, I think this does the best.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE doesn't support contentWindow.document - I think that code needs to be something like..

```
return

element.contentWindow ?
element.contentWindow.document :
ownerDocument
```